# HTML validation error - different label css on different views

Tags: html, css

If I want to control the placing of the html validation error label I can easily do so by doing this:

```
label.error {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

The only thing with this is that it then changes the position of the error label for every view where there is validation.

Is there any way I can have different margin values on the error label for different views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  label.error {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }
}
```

You need to use media queries as the above example.